# Debian 7 64bit Squid3 Server Won't Start

Tags: proxy, debian, squid

I've been having trouble running squid3.  I've set a squid3 proxy server before successfully and this is the first time encountered this error.  Basically whenever I try to start squid3 I get

[....] Starting Squid HTTP Proxy 3.x: squid3/etc/init.d/squid3: line 72: cd: HOME not set
. ok

and it doesn't do anything. Im not really sure what this means and the googling I have done hasn't turned up anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a find_cache_dir in /etc/init.d/squid3 that parse /etc/squid3/squid.conf to try to find the value of the cache_dir directive.

If cache dir is commented, find_cache_dir return nothing.

then cd $cache_dir return "cd: HOME not set" but it starts squid on my setup.

uncomment cache_dir in /etc/squid3/squid.conf stops displaying this error.